# ¿Puedo omitir una excepción en Java?

Tags: java, javafx, excepciones

Quisiera compartir un problema que tengo con respecto a una excepción en Java la cual me controla un parseo de String a Date.

El caso es que yo tengo un formulario, en el cual le estoy validando los campos, está validación trata de que si los campos están vacíos me los señale en rojo. Bueno, pero ahí viene mi problema, cuando dejo los campos vacíos, incluyendo el campo donde recibo la fecha, en ese campo, me salta la excepción, diciéndome que no puedo dejar ese campo vacío (abajo colocaré la excepción). Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de evitar que esta excepción "salte" a la hora de verificar esos campos. Por otro lado, quisiera saber si las excepciones no afectan el flujo normal del programa como lo hace un error de sintaxis o de declaración y si es recomendable dejarla o evitarlas. Aclaro que ya intenté comentando la excepción que se encuentra en el cacth, y me deja de saltar la excepción, pero no sé si sea una buena práctica de programación hacer esto.

```
@FXML public void buttonsEmployeCreate() {


    btnEmpRegister.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {

        try {  

            //Cambia el estado (Color) y limpia los JFXTextField:
            StylePersonal.StylePersonalCreate(textName, textLastName, textDni, textUserName,
                    textPassword, textDate, msgEmpty);
            //Parseo de String a Date
            SimpleDateFormat fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
            Date parseo = fecha.parse(textDate.getText());
            java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parseo.getTime());

            empleadoGeneric.setCedula(textDni.getText());
            empleadoGeneric.setNombre(textName.getText());
            empleadoGeneric.setApellido(textLastName.getText());
            empleadoGeneric.setGenero(textGender.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getGenero());
            empleadoGeneric.getUsuario().setUser(textUserName.getText());
            empleadoGeneric.getUsuario().setPassword(textPassword.getText());
            empleadoGeneric.setFecha_nto(sql);
            empleadoGeneric.getUsuario().setRol(textRol.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getRol());

            //Acceso a la JDBC:
            registrarEmpleado.registrarEmpleado(conexion.getConexion(), textName, textLastName, 
                    textDni, textRol, textUserName, textPassword, textDate, textGender); 

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MenuAdminController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    });
}
```

Se me olvidaba, estoy trabando con la tecnología Maven y JavaFx, el código anterior es el método donde recibo los datos de este formulario:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la excepción que me lanza:

```
dic 14, 2017 10:42:03 PM com.clothing.main.controller.MenuAdminControllerlambda$buttonsEmployeCreate$10
    GRAVE: null
    java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
```

De antemano les agradezco su ayuda, si hay documentación acerca de este tipo de preguntas sería de gran ayuda que me las compartieran.

Comment: Siempre es recomendable evitar el uso de excepciones, por motivos de recursos, usar excepciones conlleva al uso de recursos de forma extra. Trata de validar si la entrada a las funciones son validas.

Comment: Las excepciones son la manera correcto y segura de manejar un error cuando este sucede. Pero la excepcion te da la cualidad de redirigir y tratar el error de forma segura, permitiendote realizar ejecuciones de codigos en caso de que esto suceda. Son extremadamente importantes

Answer (score 0):

Como primer consejo te digo que esas validaciones ANTES de enviarlas al servidor, debes validarla del lado del cliente.

Te recomiendo validar los formularios con javascript, jquery o cualquiera sea el framework que estes utilizando.

Luego, en el servidor claramente lanzará una excepción porque no estas validando que el valor que viene desde el formulario NO este vacio o `null`, estas intentando crear un objeto del tipo `Date` sobre un valor que llega como `null`, por lo tanto te recomiendo también validar eso del lado del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

No es recomendable utilizar excepciones si tu intención es recuperarte de ella y continuar el flujo luego de la excepción. Recuerda que una excepción consume más recursos que manejar un Booleano que te retorne True/False en caso una validación sea aprobada o no.
En ese sentido, podrías utilizar una expresión regular que valide que el texto ingresado (en este caso la fecha) cumpla un formato, y si no lo hace, retornar un false, o ejecutar una acción (ejemplo, mostrar una alerta al usuario para que ingrese un valor válido).

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo :)

```
boolean validateDate(String dateInString){
   String DATE_PATTERN = "TU_EXPRESIÓN_REGULAR";
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN);
   return pattern.matcher(dateInString).matches();
}
```

Espero te sirva :)

Answer (score 0):

Sin ver la linea que lanza el error, pero con la descripción del error, es debido a que intentas parsear un "" a una fecha. Obviamente, no puede,ya que el campo está vacío y te lanza el error.
Hay varios modos de enfocar este asunto:

Comprobando antes si está vacío el campo de la fecha

```
   if(!textDate.getText().isEmpty()){
    SimpleDateFormat fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
    Date parseo = fecha.parse(textDate.getText());
    java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parseo.getTime());
}
```

Otra opción es introducirlo todo dentro de un try-catch y capturar la excepción que te lance y tratarla

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
        Date parseo = fecha.parse(textDate.getText());
        java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parseo.getTime());
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("invalid date");
    }
```

En cuanto a tu pregunta de omitir una excepcion, lo que haces es capturarla con catch y dentro de él tratarla, que es lo que hacemos en este caso.